# How to use Auth0 with Electron and React in SPA?

Tags: reactjs, electron, auth0

I am using an Auth0 SPA application for React with the `@auth0/auth0-react` SDK. I want to wrap my app in Electron but also deploy it as a web app (therefore I cannot rely on using auth0 native application).

What I have tried doing is using `file:///callback` for redirect_uri (added it to the list of allowed login callbacks as well), which results in an `The specified redirect_uri 'file:///callback' does not have a registered origin` error.

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score -1):

I'd need a bit more context in what you are using. I tried simulating your situation and I got it working by:

1. Setting the Auth0Provider redirectUri to "file://callback" when the app is accessed through Electron (not to disrupt the web flow)
2. Initiate the login process with the function "loginWithPopup" instead of "loginWithRedirect" in the case of an Electron app
3. Set the allow callback URLs and allowed logout URLs with the value "file://callback", plus the web values you probably have set. In my case: "http://localhost:3000,file://callback"
4. Loaded the static React build files into the Electron webview.

Does this work for you?

Comment: what about logout?